# Java xml Parsing For Two Tags with Same Name

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, tags

I am writing a code to parse xml file. I want to retrieve the country tag values from this and save that to String[]. When I am trying to do, its retrieving only one value. But I have country tag repeated twice in xml. In future it can be thrice or 4 times and so on which is dynamic. This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<metadata>
<Country>All Countries</Country>
<Country>US - United States</Country>
</metadata>
```

This is my code:

```
private static String parseXml(String xmlData)
        throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource src = new InputSource();
    src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlData));
    Document doc = builder.parse(src);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("metadata");
    Element line = null;
    String cnt = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        NodeList country = element.getElementsByTagName("Country");
        for (int j = 0; j < country.getLength(); j++) {
            if (country != null) {
                System.out.println("Country not null " + country);
                line = (Element) country.item(0);
                if (line != null) {
                    cnt = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cnt;

}

public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
        CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
        if (cd != null) {
            return cd.getData();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: You're checking if `country` is not `null` after you call `country.getLength()`, that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not provide any possibility to store a list of countries in your code, although it iterates over all countries.

The following should help (although untested):
Change `String cnt = null;` to `List<String> = new ArrayList<String>()` and do instead of

```
for (int j = 0; j < country.getLength(); j++) {
    if (country != null) {
        System.out.println("Country not null " + country);
        line = (Element) country.item(0);
        if (line != null) {
            cnt = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
        }
    }
}
```

the following:

```
if (country != null) {
    System.out.println("Country not null " + country);
    for (int j = 0; j < country.getLength(); j++) {
        line = (Element) country.item(j);
        if (line != null) {
            cnt.add( getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have prob. When I try to append the strings from the list, I am also appending a separator of each value as ,. But the , should not be appended if its a last value of list(String). How can I do this?  cntList = parseXml(metadata.xml);
         if (cntList.size() != 0) {
          // entryCountryMap.put(id, country);
          System.out.println("Size is  ---->"
            + cntList.size());
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          if (cntList.size() >= 2) {
           for (String s : cntList) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append(",");
           }
          }

Comment: Have a look at this StringUtils.join function: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.String) : With the list `cntList` all you have to do is `StringUtils.join( cntList, ",");`, where "," is the seperator that only will be added _between_ two entries. So you will not have to check the size of the list or make a new instance of a StringBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is good. Will implement and see.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two modifications in your program

1. `item(0)` should be replaced with `item(j)`
2. You can get the value of
   country using `line.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()`

Below is updated class `XmlParser.java`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XmlParser {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> "
                + "<metadata> "
                + "<Country>All Countries</Country> "
                + "<Country>US - United States</Country> "
                + "</metadata>";
        parseXml(xml);
    }

    private static String parseXml(String xmlData)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                .newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource src = new InputSource();
        src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlData));
        Document doc = builder.parse(src);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("metadata");
        Element line = null;
        String cnt = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            NodeList country = element.getElementsByTagName("Country");
            for (int j = 0; j < country.getLength(); j++) {
                if (country != null) {
                    System.out.println("Country not null " + country);
                    line = (Element) country.item(j);
                    System.out.println("value :: " + line.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                }
            }
        }
        return cnt;

    }

    public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
        Node child = e.getFirstChild();
        if (child instanceof org.w3c.dom.CharacterData) {
            org.w3c.dom.CharacterData cd = (org.w3c.dom.CharacterData) child;
            if (cd != null) {
                return cd.getData();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

And `output` below:

> Country not null
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@51f45f2a value
>   :: All Countries
>
> Country not null com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeepNodeListImpl@51f45f2a value
>   :: US - United States

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone who spent time to solve my problem. I will try one of these solutions. It seems all solutions work properly. I will post here once My problem is solved. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        System.out
            .println(Arrays
                    .toString(parseXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><metadata><Country>All Countries</Country><Country>US - United States</Country></metadata>")));
    }

    private static String[] parseXml(String xmlData) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource src = new InputSource();
        src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlData));
        Document doc = builder.parse(src);
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("metadata");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            NodeList country = element.getElementsByTagName("Country");
            for (int j = 0; j < country.getLength(); j++) {
                list.add(country.item(j).getTextContent());
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String[] getCountries(String xmlData) throws Exception{
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource src = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlData));
    Document doc = builder.parse(src);
    NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("metadata");
    for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++){
        Element metadata = (Element)nodes.item(i);
        NodeList countries = metadata.getElementsByTagName("Country");
        for(int j = 0; j < countries.getLength(); j++){
            result.add(countries.item(j).getTextContent());
        }
    }
    return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
}
```